# Numpy polyfit .How to get exact fit for the data points provided

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, interpolation

I have x,y data points.
Using these points, I am trying to create a function to fit `50 (y points)points` to generate the corresponding `x coordinates`.
But in my plot, when I try to zoom, the plot, I can see the 50 points provided is fitting the curve, but data points are slightly deviating from the plot. There is a small change from data point (in the range on delta=.001) with respect to the line generated from the 50 points if I zoom.

How do I generate a perfect curve which fits the data points along with the 50 points provided.

[please refer the screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SxYl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code as text (properly formatted as a code-block) rather than as a linked image.

Answer (score 1):

To cover 50 points perfectly you need to increase the order of the polynom. So instead of `polyfit(x, y, 10)` try `polyfit(x, y, 49)` ?

See https://arachnoid.com/polysolve/

> A "perfect" fit (one in which all the data points are matched) can often be gotten by setting the degree of the regression to the number of data pairs minus one.